# Python IDLE Shell output compressed or maybe squeezed

Tags: python, pandas, shell, python-idle

I am running Python IDLE 3.6.5 and have a problem with the output from the print() command. When the output is more than 60 lines, IDLE shell compresses the data so I can only see the first five and last five lines. It looks like this, with three dots where the missing rows of data are:

[image: IDLE Shell compresses print() output]

I know there is a "Squeeze" feature in Python, but the output apparently looks different and provides a button to un-squeeze the text. My output screen doesn't seem to have any option to view squeezed text.

Also, I know there is also supposed to be an option to set the number of lines before squeezing or compressing starts, but my version of IDLE doesn't seem to have that option:

[image]

Is this an example of "Squeezing" output?

Comment: It looks like you're using Pandas? Please include that tag if you ask questions about it. I'm not a Pandas guy, but I think this is just the standard way that Pandas shows dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Pandas issue not IDLE.

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.options.display.max_rows=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Idle (my 3.9 version)-- Go to Idle Preferences, Select Shell/Id.  It's obvious from there how to reduce or eliminate squeezed text.  Pandas also enables you to increase or decrease limits on the rows and columns displayed.  Look for Pandas set options in Google and read the documentation from the pandas link.